# Amadeus Flight Offer Search

Tags: java, amadeus

using the Java SDK, what is the maximum of results when performing a Flight Offer Search? When looping through the returned array, it seems that the length is always 5, and it seems like there is no pagination (trying to go to the next page gives me a NullPointerException).

Also, is there a way to find out what parameters Flight Offer Search has? I tried searching the documentation and the Amadeus jar, but was not able to find anything. Specifically, I am looking for the ability to search for specific routings and choosing specific airlines, if the Self-Service APIs offer this functionality.

Thank you in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Java SDK is a wrapper on top of the API, you can find the API documentation [here](https://developers.amadeus.com/self-service/category/air/api-doc/flight-offers-search/api-reference).
In the documentation, you will find parameters to filter by airlines (includedAirlineCodes or excludedAirlineCodes). Many other parameters are available. The API offers 2 flavors:

- The `GET` version, simpler to integrate but comes with fewer parameters
- The `POST` version, which is a search as well but offering more functionalities to customize your search (you can use the body of the POST to define precisely your criteria)

Both endpoints come with many parameters to customize your request.

Flight Offers Search returns a maximum of 250 flights. You can get less than this when you use the test environment as we expose only a subset of our data. To unlock the full access you will need to "move your application to production" (you can take a look at our [Get Started](https://developers.amadeus.com/get-started/category?id=80&durl=335&parentId=NaN) to see how to do it). Make sure you do not use the parameter `max` that limits the number of flight-offers returned.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I checked out the documentation and it gave me a lot of answers. Is there a list of all available functionalities though? For example, "source" only has "GDS" in it, but trying "NDC" for example didn't work. Is there a way to access NDC fares or LCC fares without e-ticketing?

Comment: The version we have today only support GDS. We are working to publish other sources of data such as LCC in the future.